Convert any format of date string to datetime
I am reading csv file and in date column it has different format some rows using m/d/yyyy some using d-m-yyyy and others
I am using below code to convert
if(datetime.strptime(row['Date'],"%m/%d/%Y").astimezone() <= datetime.strptime("2024-03-03","%Y-%m-%d").astimezone()):
  ## do the things

if the format matches it works, but it throws error when it does not match

time data '2022-05-16' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

How can I convert string date of any format to a valid date
Thanks

Does this answer your question? How to format date string via multiple formats in python

You cannot reliably convert mixed formats due to potential ambiguities such as 11-10-2024. If you're American that's a date in November. Elsewhere it's October.

@buran, I am aware of this solution, but I am looking for a generic where I don't need to provide the list of formats, as I am not aware what are the formats I can get in rows of bunch of csv files

You didn't mention "generic solution" in your question. Also, did you check the answer by khan in the link I shared? Note the ambiguity mentioned already by others.

from datetime import datetime

def parse_date(date_str):
    formats = ["%m/%d/%Y", "%d-%m-%Y", "%Y-%m-%d"]  # Add more formats as needed
    for fmt in formats:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt).astimezone()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError("Could not parse date: {}".format(date_str))

# Example usage:
date_str = "2022-05-16"
try:
    parsed_date = parse_date(date_str)
    if parsed_date <= datetime.strptime("2024-03-03", "%Y-%m-%d").astimezone():
        ## do the things
        print(parse_date)
except ValueError as e:
    print("Error parsing date:", e)

from dateutil import parser
print(parser.parse(date_str).astimezone())


I am aware of this solution, but I am looking for a generic where I don't need to provide the list of formats, as I am not aware what are the formats I can get in rows of bunch of csv files

You can use from dateutil import parser . I have edited my answer.Please upvote me,thanks a lot

Using python try: and except ValueError: will catch the error when converting the string to a datetime is in the incorrect format.
You can apply that like so:
try:
    if(datetime.strptime(row['Date'],"%m/%d/%Y").astimezone() <= datetime.strptime("2024-03-03","%Y-%m-%d").astimezone()):
        # your code
except ValueError:
    if(datetime.strptime(row['Date'],"%Y-%m-%d").astimezone() <= datetime.strptime("2024-03-03","%Y-%m-%d").astimezone()):
        # your code

